# Populating Javascript Array of Objects with an embedded Array of Objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am new to Javascript (familiar with C/C++) and I am trying to parse out an XML file and store it in an Array of Objects.  The structure is similar to a bullet list where there is one main List item and possibly multiple List subitems:

```
var MenuLine =
[{
    label : "null",
    icon : "null",
    Subitem:
    [{
        label : "null",
        icon : "null"
    }]
}];
```

Which allows me to use the following syntax:

```
var someRandomSubitemText = MenuLine[2].Subitem[4].label;
```

I tried populating this array using the .push method:

```
var tempMenuLine = [];
var tempSubitem = [];

$(xml).find("item").each(function()
{
    tempMenuLine.label = $(xml).children("label").text();
    tempMenuLine.icon = $(xml).children("icon").text();

    $(this).children("subitem").each(function()
    {
    tempSubitem.label = $(this).children("label").text();
    tempSubitem.icon = $(this).children("icon").text();
    tempMenuLine.Subitem.push(tempSubitem);
    });
    MenuLine.push(tempMenuLine);
});
```

However this does not work since the .push method passes a reference to tempMenuLine and I am overwriting tempMenuLine with each iteration.  Is there a way that I could write directly to the MenuLine array using something similar to the following syntax?

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function(index1)
{
    MenuLine[index1].label = $(xml).children("label").text();
    MenuLine[index1].icon = $(xml).children("icon").text();

    $(this).children("subitem").each(function(index2)
    {

        MenuLine[index1].Subitem[index2].label = $(this).children("label").text();
        MenuLine[index1].Subitem[index2].icon = $(this).children("icon").text();
});

});
```

Comment: Why not recreate tempMenuLine each time, by moving the = []; inside your find?

Comment: If you place the declaration of `tempMenuLine` into the function passed to `each`, then it will not be overwritten.

Comment: I tried that but then I get an error with tempMenuLine.Subitem.push(tempSubitem) stating undefined is not an object.  Is there any way to assign the values directly to the MenuLine array using array indices instead of the .push method?

Answer (score 0):

Move your temp var declarations inside of your loops:

```
$(xml).find("item").each(function() {
    var tempMenuLine = [];
    tempMenuLine[0].label = $(xml).children("label").text();
    tempMenuLine[0].icon = $(xml).children("icon").text();
    tempMenuLine[0].Subitem = []

    $(this).children("subitem").each(function(){
        var tempSubitem = [];
        tempSubitem[0].label = $(this).children("label").text();
        tempSubitem[0].icon = $(this).children("icon").text();
        tempMenuLine[0].Subitem.push(tempSubitem);
    });
    MenuLine.push(tempMenuLine);
});
```

This way, you're initializing a new item for each iteration of the loops, removing the "link" it had to the previous item.

Comment: I tried that but then I get an error with:        tempMenuLine.Subitem.push(tempSubitem) stating: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tempMenuLine.Subitem.push')

Comment: I had to actually modify the original code posted above since: tempMenuLine[0].label generates an error : "Error: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'tempMenuLine[0].label = $(this).children("label").text()')".  Once I removed the [0], the error went away.  However I am still having the issue with the Subitem push.

Comment: Wish I could vote up but I don't have enough rep.  Once I removed the [0] and added the tempMenuLine.Subitem = [], I was able to get it working.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

A recursive solution just for fun.

```
var MenuLine = Xml2Array(xmlText, 'item');

function Xml2Array(xmlDocument, itemName) {
  if (!$(itemName, xmlDocument).length) {
    return;
  }  
  var tmpArray = [];
  $(itemName, xmlDocument).each(function() {
    tmpArray.push({
      label: $('label', this).first().text(),
      icon: $('icon', this).first().text(),
      Subitem: Xml2Array(this, 'subitem')
    });
  });
  return tmpArray;
}
```